# sd card presence detection in linux

Tags: sd-card

I would like to write a simple atari simulator program under ubuntu linux operating system.
for the ROM, I want to use SD-Card.
But I want to know how to detect if SD-Card is inserted or not.

Thanks in advance
Mahdi